# React Query: Not catching 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

When running the following code ([Repo](https://github.com/jmsherry/tanstack-router-v4)) my page fails to render entirely. There is no catch going on. The useQuery hook doesn't show an error as per this sort of [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q12EVU8YpTY&ab_channel=Codevolution).

```js
export const fetchCars = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(CARS_ENDPOINT.slice(0, -3)); // intentional 404 creation
  console.log(resp);
  if (!resp.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch");
  return await resp.json();
};
```

```js
export const useCars = ({ onSuccess, onError } = {}) =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: [STORAGE_KEY],
    queryFn: fetchCars,
    onSuccess,
    onError,
  });
```

```js
const CarsListPage = () => {

  const deleteMutation = useDelete();

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    deleteMutation.mutate(id);
  };

  const { data, isLoading, error, isError, isFetching } = useCars();

  let component = null;

  if (isLoading || isFetching) {
    component = <CircularProgress />;
  } else if (isError) {
    component = <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>;
  } else {
    component = <CarsList cars={data} deleteHandler={deleteHandler} />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h3" component="h2">
        Cars
      </Typography>
      {component}
    </>
  );
};

export default CarsListPage;
```

I'm just at a loss as to why it causes such a catastrophic break?! Can anyone help?

Thanks

EDIT:
Version: "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.26.1",

```
query.ts:444 Error: Failed to fetch
    at Object.fetchCars [as queryFn] (index.js?t=1678250720657:6:23)
onError @ query.ts:444
reject @ retryer.ts:112
(anonymous) @ retryer.ts:174
Promise.catch (async)
run @ retryer.ts:154
createRetryer @ retryer.ts:204
fetch @ query.ts:456
fetchOptimistic @ queryObserver.ts:305
fetchOptimistic @ suspense.ts:50
useBaseQuery @ useBaseQuery.ts:97
useQuery @ useQuery.ts:139
useCars @ queries.js?t=1678251342413:11
CarsListPage @ List.jsx:16
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
2useBaseQuery.ts:109 Uncaught Error: Failed to fetch
    at Object.fetchCars [as queryFn] (index.js?t=1678250720657:6:23)
fetchCars @ index.js?t=1678250720657:6
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <CarsListPage> component:

    at CarsListPage (http://localhost:5173/src/pages/List.jsx?t=1678251342413:25:26)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=544e5302:3026:5)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=544e5302:3311:26)
    at div
    at http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-27RC25JA.js?v=544e5302:3619:51
    at Container3 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-27RC25JA.js?v=544e5302:7647:19)
    at main
    at Layout (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Layout.jsx:35:7)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=544e5302:3026:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=544e5302:3371:5)
    at QueryClientProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FQOZDGIW.js?v=544e5302:2790:3)
    at UIProvider (http://localhost:5173/src/components/contexts/UI.context.jsx:30:3)
    at InnerThemeProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-27RC25JA.js?v=544e5302:6121:17)
    at ThemeProvider2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-27RC25JA.js?v=544e5302:4746:5)
    at ThemeProvider3 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-27RC25JA.js?v=544e5302:6129:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=544e5302:3318:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=544e5302:3731:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught Error: Failed to fetch
    at Object.fetchCars [as queryFn] (index.js?t=1678250720657:6:23)
```

Comment: Usually when a React page fails to render there's an error reported in the browser console. Do you have one?

Comment: What version of react-query are you using?

Comment: v4.26.1
Errors in console are as you'd expect (i.e. The error message; Which component it originated in and; the suggestion to use an ErrorBoundary.) Not very helpful, sadly!

Comment: That's not very clear. Could you please [edit] your question with the error information? Even a screenshot would be better than nothing

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/new-platform-fj3y1x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's odd. Can I ask, if you clone the repo and run it does it work for you?

Comment: I note you've got `suspense: true` in [your QueryClient configuration](https://github.com/jmsherry/tanstack-router-v4/blob/main/src/App.jsx#L24). You should probably read the [Suspense](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/suspense) docs before using it

Comment: @Phil: That's the one! (I'd left that in from another branch where I'm demoing suspense). Thanks Phil!

IDK if you want to put that as the answer? (as it is a mistake but one someone could make if they were copying over config)